# Countries to allow my iOS application in?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

I've a question regarding to releasing my iOS application.

Is there anything I should think about when releasing? Should I let ALL countries be able to download the application, if not why?

I mean, I've no idea about all the countries rules regarding to everything. On my IOS app I've a map which you can start and it will track your moves till you press a stop button. And I also have links to "third-party's (To shops, blogs, instagram accounts etc)"

Should I allow my app in all countries? If not, which one should I remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really an offtopic question, countries you want to distribute your app to depend on your business logic. Unless you have some questionable content (for example China has some strict rules regarding content and maps) or store user data without GDPR (European Union), you're almost certainly good to go.